# Why does subclassing change the __init__ signature?

Tags: python

```
>>> map(int, ["1", "2"], kw=True)
TypeError: map() takes no keyword arguments
```

But when subclassing

```
>>> class Map(map):
...     pass
...
>>> Map(int, ["1", "2"], whydoesthiswork=True)
<__main__.Map at 0x10fe48700>
```

Why does this now accept keyword argument? Shouldn't it just inherit the `__init__`from parent?

Comment: My guess is that `map`, being implemented in C, does not precisely follow the same rules as `Map`, which is an ordinary user-defined class that just inherits from `map`.

Comment: I'll note that `map.__init__` and `Map.__init__` resolve to the same object, as do `map.__new__` and `Map.__new__`. However, `map.__call__` and `Map.__call__` are *different* objects, which suggests something about `map` is defined, as their types alone indicate that they are not simply inherited from `type`.

Comment: (`type.__call__` is a slot wrapper, and instance of `wrapper_descriptor`, while `map.__call__` and `Map.__call__` are distinct instances of `method-wrapper`.)

Comment: @chepner I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: TL;DR `map` is special, because it is defined by the CPython implementation, not using a `class` statement, so it follows different rules.

Comment: So how do you make a subclass just keep the parent's signature, without having to care about whether the superclass is "special" or not?

Comment: You can't. The very *fact* that `map` is special is what (potentially) makes you have to acknowledge its special nature.

Comment: I would think long and hard about why you think you need to subclass `map`. Just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: It's not only map, I've just used that as a simple example.  This happens with a lot of other types e.g. zip, filter, reversed ...

Comment: Also, according to its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) `map()` is a function, _not_ a class, so subclassing it doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: @martineau That's Python 2; `map` is a class in Python 3. The page you link fails to make that clarification. (I think it's an intentional oversight for the purposes of that page, to maintain some consistency from Python 2 to Python 3.)

Comment: I see type(map) is type, not function.

Comment: @chepner: I linked to the Python 3 documentation (and it's in the [Built-in Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions) section.

Comment: Well the table may says "Built-in Functions" but it has other stuff in there which are obviously types (int, float, dict)

Comment: @martineau Just because the page claims to be documenting built-in functions doesn't mean everything on that page really is a function. `type` is on that list, and it was actually a type even in Python 2. (It may have been a function prior to the introduction of new-style classes; I don't recall.)

Comment: @chepner: True, under the heading it does say "has a number of functions and types" in the first paragraph. Perhaps it's because classes (types) are callable like functions are in Python.

Comment: Yeah, "functions", not "`function`s" :)

Comment: @chepner  So why it follows different rules? Why would it follow a rule that changes the init signature, CPython dev could have made it inherit the similar way as for ordinary user-defined class couldn't they, so what is the reason for not doing that?

Comment: @nosteponsnek If I knew that, I would post an answer. All I know (as demonstrated by your question) is that `map` behaves differently from a subclass of `map`. I don't think `__init__` is involved at all here; I think somehow it is the call to `map` that objects to keyword arguments before it ever delegates anything to `map.__new__` or `map.__init__`. That's why I pointed out the discrepancy between `map.__call__` and `Map.__call__`.

Comment: What `__call__` has to do with it? Isn't that what's used for calling on a map *instance* (i.e. the return value of a map)?

Comment: @nosteponsnek Maybe you could explain your specific use-case - What is it that you're doing that makes you think you need to inherit from `map`, or `zip` or `filter` or `reversed`?

Comment: But classes are instances of metaclasses, so it's the *metaclass*'s `__call__` method that I'm talking about. `Map(...)`, for instance, is basically short for `type.__call__(Map, ...)`, whose implementation calls `Map.__new__`, passes the result to `Map.__init__`, then returns that result. Something about `map(...)` makes me think that it is *not* exactly the same as `type.__call__(map, ...)`. Because it is implemented in C, it may bypass certain parts of the normal process in `map`-specific ways that don't necessarily correspond to how any other type would work.

Comment: @martineau (and everyone else): The Python docs document the Python *language*. For Python, `map` and `filter` are callables (functions) that return iterators.  In CPython, `type(map)` is `type`.  But this is an implementation detail.  Another Python implementation could define map and filter as generator functions.  CPython does not do that because generator functions can only be defined in Python, and the C class instances runs faster.  For the same reason, the itertools module (now) has C-coded iterator classes which are documented in part by a closely equivalent generator function.

Comment: @chepner `map` is not documented as a class because being a class is a CPython implementation detail and not part of the Python language definition.  See comment above. I am thinking that this should be mentioned.  This means that `class M(map): pass` is currently legal in CPython (which surprises me a bit) but not necessarily as Python code. `zip` is another iterator function implemented in CPython as a C class.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Hm, I do notice now that certain things on that page (`map` not among them) are explicitly documented as classes (`int`, `list`, etc.).

Comment: @chepner Right. Those are defined as classes in the language and, unlike the iterator classes, have documented public methods and attributes.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why, but `map.__new__` specifically [*only* rejects keyword arguments](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1200) if the class being instantiated is `map` itself:

```
if (type == &PyMap_Type && !_PyArg_NoKeywords("map", kwds))
    return NULL;
```

This is basically the C-level equivalent of

```
def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if cls is map and kwargs:
        raise TypeError
    ...
```

The furthest back I've been able to trace this code is [this merge](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b213704f3cad4fc61c4117afe559454b02193e5b), which includes a change that added checks like this to a bunch of itertools types back when this version of `map` was still `itertools.imap`. One of the commit messages is "Bug #1486663: don't reject keyword arguments for subclasses of builtin types.", which seems to be referring to a bug from an old (now-gone?) tracker, but it's not clear why rejecting keyword arguments ever would have been considered a bug - if subclasses want to take keyword arguments a superclass doesn't take, they shouldn't forward those arguments to the superclass `__new__`.

Comment: *"if subclasses want to take keyword arguments a superclass doesn't take, they shouldn't forward those arguments to the superclass `__new__`."* Normally, a subclass doesn't override `__new__` at all; if you had said this about `__init__`, I would absolutely agree. Perhaps the reason `__new__` does this check is because classes defined in C don't have proper `__init__` methods?

Comment: @kaya3: Classes defined in C can use `__init__` just fine. For example, [here's `list.__init__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Objects/listobject.c#L2672).

Comment: Also note that, for example, `tuple.__new__` doesn't have this weird check. It just rejects keyword arguments outright. If you want a `tuple` subclass to take keyword arguments, you have to override `__new__` properly and pass `tuple.__new__` the arguments it expects.

Comment: Actually I see the same behavior of accepting and ignoring kwargs with `class Tuple(tuple): pass`.

Comment: @nosteponsnek: wait what the - you're right, but I don't see how that's supposed to work in the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.9.2/Objects/tupleobject.c#L684), and [it wasn't like that before](https://bugs.python.org/issue43413).

Comment: I guess Argument Clinic must be doing some kind of weird special casing.